# SQL Cursor to determine median value

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor

I am trying to write a Stored Procedure to retrieve the median salary from a table and am having trouble figuring out how to retrieve the data from the cursor.
Currently my code is:

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MedianSalary(OUT median INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE counter int(5) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE set_size int(5) DEFAULT (SELECT count(*) from employee);
DECLARE median_index int(5) DEFAULT (SELECT floor(count/2));


DECLARE all_salaries CURSOR

FOR SELECT salary from employee,
OPEN all_salaries;

WHILE @counter != @median_index
BEGIN
 SET @counter = @counter + 1,
 FETCH NEXT from all_salaries,
END;

FETCH all_salaries INTO median;

CLOSE all_salaries;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I can't seem to find any documentation similar to what I am trying to achieve, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because no-one would ever use a cursor for this. If you are working in a database you have got to forget about procedural programming. I'm sure you can find a query to do this pretty easily.

Comment: @TomC I wouldn't say finding the median is pretty easy in MySQL, but I just did it in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer to your stored procedure problem, but note that we can actually find the median from a table in MySQL fairly easily using session variables to simulate the row number:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @row_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable);

SELECT AVG(salary) AS median
FROM
(
    SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rn, salary
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY salary
) t
WHERE
    (@row_count % 2 = 0 AND rn IN (@row_count / 2, (@row_count / 2) + 1) OR
     @row_count % 2 <> 0 AND rn = @row_count / 2);
```

### Demo

Note the ugliness in the `WHERE` clause has to do with the edge case of your table having an *even* number of records.  In this case, there technically is not a single median record, so instead I report the *mean* of the two records which sit about the median on either side.

Comment: Will MySQL optimise all those `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable` subqueries into 1? Regardless it might be clearer (given you're setting variables anyway) to `SET @row_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable);` and use that?

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the input, that really helps.  Not sure if MySQL would optimize those away.  I might expect it, because those subqueries are not correlated, but then again it might not.

Comment: a 30 second google search revealed a similar answer, with the where clause actually kind of neat: `where rn IN (FLOOR(@rowindex / 2) , CEIL(@rowindex / 2))`

Comment: @TomC If you can find an exact duplicate on SO, then feel free to nail the question closed.

Comment: Looks much better! :)

Comment: This was elsewhere - I just did a google search and it turned up on a site called eversql. Search was "sql find median value".

Comment: Thanks to you both! I'll give it a go, I was only attempting to use cursors as that was what was asked of me but this seems the better route to go and will work better for the next iteration. Much appreciated!

Comment: Worked great just as I imagined! Thanks again, I'll mark this as correct.